# Alamofire request not being executed after adding one parameter

Tags: swift, parameters, httprequest, alamofire

I have this function. Whenever I comment the "v": 2 parameter it works like a charm, then I add it and when trying to call the function from my VC it doesn't get fired off. I think the problem is somewhere at the top. Like I said, when commenting the "v:2" parameter, everything goes smooth. I've checked my postman and the URL Request adding that parameter does give me the right response, but my function is not being called in my VC. Any ideas? Please I'm desperate ):

```
public func getBusinessBy(location loc: String, type: Int, loading: Bool, OnSuccess success: @escaping (_ businesses: [NSDictionary]) -> Void, OnFailed failed: @escaping (_ error: String) -> Void) {

        if loading {
            GlobalLoader.show()
        }
        
        let bUrl = HttpUtils.getBusinessesBy(type: type)
        let params: Parameters = [
            "location": loc,
            "type": type,
            "v": 2,
            "params": Config.ENABLE_SEARCH ? Config.SEARCH_BUSINESS_PARAMS : Config.COMMON_BUSINESS_PARAMS,
        ]
        Alamofire.request(bUrl, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: [:]).responseJSON() { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let val):
                print("yaaaaay!")
                if let res = val as? NSDictionary {
                    if let businesses = res.results() {
                        let allBusiesses = businesses.sorted(by: { (d1, d2) -> Bool in
                            (d1.object(forKey: "open") as! Bool) && !(d2.object(forKey: "open") as! Bool)
                        }) 
// Storing All Businesses to global
                        Session.sharedInstance.setAllBusiness(allBusiesses)
                            var tmpCat = [NSDictionary]()
                            var tmpPro = [NSDictionary]()
                            var tmpPMotion = [NSDictionary]()
                            var tmpPBusiness = [NSDictionary]()
                            
                            for busin in allBusiesses {
                                guard let categories = busin["categories"] as? [NSDictionary] else {
                                    return
                                }
                                tmpCat.append(contentsOf: categories)
                                var flag = false
                                
                                for cat in categories {
                                    if let prod = cat["products"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                                        for p in prod {
                                            var pClone = NSMutableDictionary()
                                            pClone = p.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
                                            let pivot = NSMutableDictionary()
                                            pivot["business_id"] = busin.getId()
                                            pivot["business_name"] = busin.getName()
                                            pivot["business_description"] = busin.getDescription()
                                            pivot["business_enabled"] = busin.isOpened()
                                            pivot["category_name"] = cat.getName()
                                            pivot["category_description"] = cat.getDescription()
                                            pivot["category_enabled"] = cat.isEnabled()
                                            pClone["pivot"] = pivot
                                            tmpPro.append(pClone)
                                            if p.isFeatured() {
                                                tmpPMotion.append(pClone)
                                                if !flag {
                                                    tmpPBusiness.append(busin)
                                                    flag = true
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            Session.sharedInstance.setAllProduct(tmpPro)
                            Session.sharedInstance.setPromotions(tmpPMotion)
                            Session.sharedInstance.setPromBusinesses(tmpPBusiness)
                            Session.sharedInstance.setAllCategory(tmpCat)
//                        }
                        success(businesses)
                    }
                } else {
                    failed(val as? String ?? "Passing error!")
                }
                if loading {
//                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    GlobalLoader.hide()
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print("naaaaay!")
                failed(error.localizedDescription)
                if loading {
//                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    GlobalLoader.hide()
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats the error message you are seeing,

Comment: I'm not getting any error, on the contrary, everything seems "fine" but when trying to call the function from my VC it doesn't work. If I remove the "v":2 param it works just fine ):

Comment: are you sure you are not getting any error  message in the Xcode console ?

Comment: Yeah, my func just doesn't get called from my HomeVC ): when printing the response from others vcs  it works just fine.